# Add a sheet counter in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

i have a excel file with a lot of sheets. i want to make a sheet counter to put in a specific cell of each one of those sheets "sheet x of Y"
for example, if you are on the sheet 3 of 5, in the cell "X5" must to say "sheet 2" and in the cell "X6" say "of 5"
each sheet have a button to add other sheet, so the sheet counter must be update every time you add a sheet

i tried this code but doesn't work, it only puts "0" in the first sheet

```
Public Sub CountWorkSheets()
If Application.Sheets.Count = 2 Then
Sheets(1).Range("X5").Value = 1 And Sheets(2).Range("X5").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest go to `ThisWorkbook` and hook into the `NewSheet` event

[image: scr]

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call AddSheetCounters
End Sub

Public Sub AddSheetCounters()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    n = Me.Sheets.Count
    
    For i = 1 To n
        Me.Sheets(i).Range("X5").Value = "Sheet " & i
        Me.Sheets(i).Range("X6").Value = "of " & n
    Next i

End Sub
```

Edit the text for ranges `X5` and `X6` as you need. Every time a new sheet is added the macro is run. Unfortunately when a sheet is deleted, it won't and things will get out of sync.